# Eclipse Jobs API for a stand-alone Swing project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am looking into the [Eclipse Jobs API](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html) and was wondering if anyone has used it in a stand-alone Swing project (aka not Eclipse RCP)?  Also is there any another competing framework like the Jobs API?

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the jars for 3 plugins (and the osgi jar is about 1Meg) but you don't have to run OSGi to run a Job.  Just include `org.eclipse.equinox.common`, `org.eclipse.osgi`, and `org.eclipse.core.jobs`.  Then you subclass `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job`, instantiate it, and schedule it.

You would have to install your own org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.ProgressProvider to get a useful IProgressMonitor that would display back to your swing UI

Comment: You're right.  I had a look at the imports to Job and JobManager.  I always thought that the Job API depended on resources not the other way around.  I'm surprised.  I deleted my answer.  Thanks for teaching me.  :)